# Using PowerShell to Get SharePoint Content database size

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What's the powershell command to get the all `Content_DB` size in `SharePoint` server(MB)?

Maybe?

```
Get-SPDatabase | Sort-Object disksizerequired -desc | Format-Table Name, @{Label ="Size in MB"; Expression = {$_.disksizerequired/1024/1024}}
```

Comment: You did not actually ask a question.

Comment: It does not look like  a question at all

Comment: Its answer,am sharing the my knowledge

Comment: create a blog site to share your knowledge

Answer (score 4):

If you need Export the report using below commands

```
Get-SPDatabase | Sort-Object disksizerequired -desc | Format-Table Name, @{Label ="Size in MB"; Expression = {$_.disksizerequired/1024/1024}} > c:\Content_DataBaseSize.txt
```